# Could not load Main.Storyboard in XCUITest

Tags: swift, tdd, xctest, xcode12, xcuitest

I am try to make UITestCase for UIViewcontrollers, But when I load main storyboard in my `QuizAppUITests`, It could not identify from `Bundle` and it's gives below error

> Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CC199C69-F398-4A7C-882E-BFD3E72B95D3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BCC3F88D-E08C-4491-8340-699EAF98AB28/QuizAppUITests-Runner.app> (loaded) (NSInvalidArgumentException)

[image]

I have added Main Storyboard in QuizAppUITests Target as well
And below is my code for test

```
import XCTest
@testable import QuizApp

class QuizViewControllerUITests: XCTestCase {
    func makeSUT() -> QuizViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
        let sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuizViewController") as! QuizViewController
        _ = sut.view
        return sut
    }
    
    func test_loadQuizViewController() {
        let sut = makeSUT()
        sut.headerQuestion = "Q1"
        XCTAssertEqual(sut.headerQuestion, "Q1")
    }

}
```

Is there any required to change in BuildSetting of `QuizAppUITests` Target?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't know why are you using storyboard for UITest. There other way better ways for UITesting in iOS.

Comment: Agreed this is a very strange way to use XCUITest. It's like a unit test UI test.

Comment: @Kudos I want to check instantiateViewController from storyboard and storyboard exist in Bundle or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of this makes sense for a UI test. Instead, put your code into your unit test target, which is `QuizAppTests`.

My book *[iOS Unit Testing by Example](https://pragprog.com/titles/jrlegios/ios-unit-testing-by-example/)* has a chapter called "Load View Controllers". Looking there for what it says about storyboard-based view controllers:

- Don't include the storyboard in your test target. Put it only in your app target.
- Then you can load the storyboard with `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`
- There's a new way to instantiate the view controller that doesn't require force-casting. Instead of `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`, use `instantiateViewController(identifier:)` and assign it to an explicitly typed variable.

Like this:

```
let sut: QuizViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
    identifier: "QuizViewController"
)
```

Since you use the name of the class as the identifier, we can even get rid of the string. This protects us from typos, at compile time:

```
let sut: QuizViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
    identifier: String(describing: QuizViewController.self)
)
```

Finally, instead of `_ = sut.view`, we can be more explicit about loading the view:

```
sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

This hooks up the outlet connections.

Again, all this belongs in your unit test target `QuizAppTests`, not your UI test target `QuizAppUITests`.

For your actual tests, don't just assign a property in your system under test and check that it was assigned. That doesn't prove anything. Instead, I'd focus on testing:

- That outlets are not nil
- That interacting with controls does what you want
- That navigation works
- That view appearance hasn't changed from an approved snapshot

This can all be done with TDD.